# Exporting canvas to xps vb

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xps

Hi today I tried to export my canvas to a file. First I tried to export it to a png and it worked fine, everything looks the same as on the canvas.

After that I modified my code to export to a xps file.

```
    Dim thePack As IO.Packaging.Package = IO.Packaging.Package.Open(path.LocalPath,IO.FileMode.Create)
    Dim doc As New Xps.Packaging.XpsDocument(thePack)
    Dim writer As Xps.XpsDocumentWriter = Xps.Packaging.XpsDocument.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(doc)
    writer.Write(mycanvas)
    doc.Close()
    thePack.Close()
```

The code runs fine but it doesn't generate the exact same view as on my canvas/png.

Are there any functions to change the output of the writer? 
It seems like the visual objects are moved lower then the text inside them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why but dropshadow was giving me an issue.

```
       <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="rand" Style="{DynamicResource BorderStyle}" >
           <Border.Effect>
               <DropShadowEffect  Direction="45" Color="#DDDDDD"/>
           </Border.Effect>
       </Border>
```

After I removed the border.effect from my usercontrol the xps file was generated flawlessly.

```
     <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="rand" Style="{DynamicResource BorderStyle}" >
    </Border>
```